# Does rocket increase power in own reference frame as speed increase?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames, power, rocket-science

In reference frame moving with rocket exhaust speed is constant, so what is with power as speed increase?

If power is const. in this frame, how is possible that at frame at rest power rise?
Shouldn't any frame you choose must produce same results in physics?

Comment: The laws are frame independent, but quantities are not necessarily so. Energy is frame-dependent.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Conservation of mass energy and kinetic energy in different reference frames](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/91589/)

Comment: There are probably other related questions, but I was afraid that that rabbit hole was too deep.